# How to run Avalonia app on Ubuntu 22.04? Some libhostfxr.so: invalid ELF header error

Tags: c#, .net, linux, ubuntu, avalonia

I'm trying to run Avalonia App on Ubuntu 22.04 and get this error:

```
Failed to load /home/nikita/Downloads/Project/Pro/libhostfxr.so, error: /home/nikita/Downloads/Project/Pro/libhostfxr.so: invalid ELF header
The library libhostfxr.so was found, but loading it from /home/nikita/Downloads/Project/Pro/libhostfxr.so failed
  - Installing .NET prerequisites might help resolve this problem.
     https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2063370
```

When I run same app on clean (without .NET dependencies installed) Ubuntu 20.04 - it's ok.

I build app from Windows with command:

```
dotnet publish ..\Project\ -o ..\Release\Ubuntu\Project\ --runtime ubuntu.22.04-x64 --configuration Release --self-contained true
```

I guess that it's can be some trouble of build cause if I install dotnet and build project directly from ubuntu 22.04 - it runs, but with some problems like black background :D
[run native ubuntu build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGcbM.png)

Please help me understand where the problem can be :) Thanks!

Avalonia v0.10.18